# postgresql выборка лимитированного количества строк начиная от строки с определенным uuid

Tags: postgresql

Знаю про `LIMIT` и `OFFSET` теперь пытаюсь разобраться, возможно ли сделать выборку допустим 20 строк (что то вроде LIMIT 20) из таблицы `table`, отсортированной по полю `name` `ASC`, начиная от строки с каким то определенным uuid?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT d1.* FROM
(SELECT Row_Number() over (order by name) AS RowIndex, * from table) AS d1 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT Row_Number() over (order by name) AS RowIndex, * from table) AS d2 
ON (d2.uuid  = 'fa77bc6c-97de-4a8a-843c-c98fc1125163' and d1.RowIndex > d2.RowIndex) LIMIT 10
```